# Deconding base64 API response throws a FormatException

Tags: dart

An API I'm working on returns the following Base64, UTF8 Data.

> H4sIAAAAAAAEAIXS3WvCMBAA8H8l5MmB9Wtf2idtJ86HDrHKNsYeYntrgzUpl2RQpf/7UsExsXZvCcf97ri7A0XQBsUT04y6BzoGRIlAXUrbFDIQkZx+g9D8GBR4+tChjY8NZgvOtGZfEnc2n6Za58rtdk3EOwnoQhqEKqMjRcYFVGb1ldT9sByPf7l+xcWgIuR7LkXVwKDXH5G1PyfByiOvErOY+Cnb5TasUp4rskBQNh1isilIABiBBRwPxJ60Aik0CRm3YTIRAhx/8nJDy/Z51duGqkvJ4tqyrXeJW/tEcGbe8hK9a0DXuGGiXvVTEElsHP+5ptH7OnPQO5p+EWWS+CiVqpMvrIcr1vkEj4OXRmg7Q+LxLZxsk1+Ijw3decEbCU1u7b8N1iDDBmSFLNr+fwMrrpTUpOUB2mtzZtOa7Ywaylxf+YQnGTgBQ80TUZBwPbfyZ1mWP1eCbD1AAwAA

I wrote the following test to convert it to a UTF8 Json string.

```
void main() {
  const data = "H4sIAAAAAAAEAIXS3WvCMBAA8H8l5MmB9Wtf2idtJ86HDrHKNsYeYntrgzUpl2RQpf/7UsExsXZvCcf97ri7A0XQBsUT04y6BzoGRIlAXUrbFDIQkZx+g9D8GBR4+tChjY8NZgvOtGZfEnc2n6Za58rtdk3EOwnoQhqEKqMjRcYFVGb1ldT9sByPf7l+xcWgIuR7LkXVwKDXH5G1PyfByiOvErOY+Cnb5TasUp4rskBQNh1isilIABiBBRwPxJ60Aik0CRm3YTIRAhx/8nJDy/Z51duGqkvJ4tqyrXeJW/tEcGbe8hK9a0DXuGGiXvVTEElsHP+5ptH7OnPQO5p+EWWS+CiVqpMvrIcr1vkEj4OXRmg7Q+LxLZxsk1+Ijw3decEbCU1u7b8N1iDDBmSFLNr+fwMrrpTUpOUB2mtzZtOa7Ywaylxf+YQnGTgBQ80TUZBwPbfyZ1mWP1eCbD1AAwAA";
  
  test('Base64 decoder', () {
    final bytes = base64.decode(data);

    String jsonString;
    try {
      jsonString = utf8.decode(bytes);  
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
    }
    
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print("$jsonString\n");

    final decoded = json.decode(jsonString);
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print("$decoded\n");
    expect(decoded, !null);
  });
}
```

The bytes that get decoded from the base64 string look good to me, but when I try to `utf8.decode()` the bytes. I get a `FormatException`, or, if I add `allowMalformed = true`, a non-sense string.

How can I decode the Json string correctly?

Comment: The base64 decoded input string is not valid in UTF-8. Check it here: https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: @Mobina I tried there and I got the same result, I talked with the person dealing with the server and he told me that I'm actually getting an array of bytes, and that I should convert it accordingly. As far as I know, it should be done automatically by the when I get it by calling `response.body`.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your BASE64 input is a GZip compressed JSON String. The following program will work:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  const data = "H4sIAAAAAAAEAIXS3WvCMBAA8H8l5MmB9Wtf2idtJ86HDrHKNsYeYntrgzUpl2RQpf/7UsExsXZvCcf97ri7A0XQBsUT04y6BzoGRIlAXUrbFDIQkZx+g9D8GBR4+tChjY8NZgvOtGZfEnc2n6Za58rtdk3EOwnoQhqEKqMjRcYFVGb1ldT9sByPf7l+xcWgIuR7LkXVwKDXH5G1PyfByiOvErOY+Cnb5TasUp4rskBQNh1isilIABiBBRwPxJ60Aik0CRm3YTIRAhx/8nJDy/Z51duGqkvJ4tqyrXeJW/tEcGbe8hK9a0DXuGGiXvVTEElsHP+5ptH7OnPQO5p+EWWS+CiVqpMvrIcr1vkEj4OXRmg7Q+LxLZxsk1+Ijw3decEbCU1u7b8N1iDDBmSFLNr+fwMrrpTUpOUB2mtzZtOa7Ywaylxf+YQnGTgBQ80TUZBwPbfyZ1mWP1eCbD1AAwAA";

  final bytes = base64.decode(data);

  String jsonString;
  try {
    jsonString = utf8.decode(GZipCodec().decode(bytes));
  } catch (e) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print(e);
  }

  // ignore: avoid_print
  print("$jsonString\n");

  final dynamic decoded = json.decode(jsonString);
  // ignore: avoid_print
  print("$decoded\n");
}
```

Returns:

```
{"returnData":{"@errore":"","elencoEventi":{"@nrEventi":"8","@urlPiattaforma":"https://uci.getyourevent.online","evento":[{"@idEventi":"1","@descrizione":"2019 UCI MTB World Championships Presented by Mercedes-Benz (Mont Sainte Anne-CAN)"},{"@idEventi":"3","@descrizione":"2019 UCI Road World Championships (Yorkshire-GBR)"},{"@idEventi":"4","@descrizione":"2019 UCI Urban World Championships (Chengdu-CHN)"},{"@idEventi":"5","@descrizione":"2020 UCI Cyclo Cross World Championships"},{"@idEventi":"6","@descrizione":"2020 Mercedes-Benz UCI Mountain Bike World Cup"},{"@idEventi":"7","@descrizione":"2020 UCI BMX Supercross World Cup"},{"@idEventi":"8","@descrizione":"2020 UCI Track World Championships Presented by Tissot (Berlin-GER)"},{"@idEventi":"9","@descrizione":"2020 UCI Road World Championships (Aigle-Martigny SUI)"}]}}}

{returnData: {@errore: , elencoEventi: {@nrEventi: 8, @urlPiattaforma: https://uci.getyourevent.online, evento: [{@idEventi: 1, @descrizione: 2019 UCI MTB World Championships Presented by Mercedes-Benz (Mont Sainte Anne-CAN)}, {@idEventi: 3, @descrizione: 2019 UCI Road World Championships (Yorkshire-GBR)}, {@idEventi: 4, @descrizione: 2019 UCI Urban World Championships (Chengdu-CHN)}, {@idEventi: 5, @descrizione: 2020 UCI Cyclo Cross World Championships}, {@idEventi: 6, @descrizione: 2020 Mercedes-Benz UCI Mountain Bike World Cup}, {@idEventi: 7, @descrizione: 2020 UCI BMX Supercross World Cup}, {@idEventi: 8, @descrizione: 2020 UCI Track World Championships Presented by Tissot (Berlin-GER)}, {@idEventi: 9, @descrizione: 2020 UCI Road World Championships (Aigle-Martigny SUI)}]}}}
```